# Google map v3 - how to bind event with the service of Gmap

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-3

I am stuck with strange situation with Google maps v3. When an user clicks on google map, we are throwing our registration `div`s on top of map & capturing user details. But the problem is when an user zooms in they reach to below situation

[image]

Now suppose if the user clicks on small icon for places like hospitals, schools, colleges etc (Do not known exactly what to say about these icon in term of gmap), it ignores the Click event written & google throws the infoWindow on screen.

How can I disable this default behavior? How can I bind my event with this? So when user click on these icon (Do not known exactly what to say about these icon in term of gmap), they will my registration divs on gmap.

Comment: Make sure you are using live with jquery click event on button or div

Comment: How about adding a transparent div on top of the map with a click handler that shows the registration form. Once registered the div can be removed and your map behaves like a normal map.

Comment: Gruff, my point is how to disable this default behavior/bind my event with this?

Comment: Hi Narendra. What I was trying to explain was to have a div covering the whole of the map with a click handler on that div that performed the registration. That way you wouldn't have to muck about adding map listeners on the map to perform the registration. Once registration is done, remove the div and let the map behave like a map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write "*Do not known exactly what to say about these icon in term of gmap*", then I think : Why dont you just get rid of them? If I understand you correctly, you are simply annoyed over the default "points of interests"-icons and so on, which "steals" your clicks?

You can remove *anything* (yes, so it is just a gray background) from a google map v3 by using [styles](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapTypeStyle). Simply create a `styles`-array and assign it to your `options` :

```
var styles = [
   {
    elementType: "all",
    featureType: "poi",
    stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }]
   },
   {   
    elementType : "all",
    featureType: "administrative",
    stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }]
   }
];
```

Here `visibility` for all administration-icons (including subcategories) and all poi's, "points of interest" (including subcategories) is set to off. [Documentation for all featureTypes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#MapTypeStyleFeatureType). You can be rather detailed in what you want to show on the map, and also how you want to show whats left.

Use the styles as param value in your regular options, eg

```
var options = {
  center: mapCenter,
  zoom: 10,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  zoomControl: true,
  streetViewControl: false,
  styles : styles
}

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);
```

And now your map is cleaned for hospitals, schools and more.

Answer (score 0):

function initMap() {

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {

zoom: 4,

center: {lat: 41.3103509, lng: 69.2732513}  // Uzbekistan.
  });

Comment: Please explain in what way this answers the question and how to use it